# SQL Keyword search algorithm: This SQL does a sequential search, how to do an indexed search?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, search-engine

We have three tables to hold our products and keywords:

```
Product {int ID, string name, ...}
ProductKeyword {int productID, int keywordID}
Keyword {int ID, string keyword}
```

This SQL code returns the most relevant products to the least relevant products having keywords like the users search criteria.  searchWordTable is a table of search words.  `@keywordCount` is a count of the search words.  This returns all the products having one or more keywords, ordered by the quantity of keywords found for each product.

```
select productid, productname, count(*) * 1 / @keywordCount as percentRelevant
from (select keyword, productid, productname
      from   product
             join productkeyword on ... 
             join keyword on ...
             join searchWordTable on searchwordtable.keyword like 
                  '%' + keyword.keyword + '%') K -- like join aweful
group by productid, productname
order by percentRelevant desc -- Most relevant first
```

The problem is this is a sequential search comparing every keyword we have.  It's not bad, but searches can take a minute with a million records.

How could I rewrite the query to not use `like`, hopefully use an indexed search, and get similar results?  They use `like` to get partial matches, e.g., 'bone' in 'boneless'.

Links to better SQL algorithms would surely be appreciated.

Comment: In your example ("bone" in "boneless") you could omit the first "%" and - bang - an index can be used.

Comment: That is a very good idea.  If we could limit our keywords to single words, that would work pretty well.  We have keywords similar to 'Kelloggs Corn Flakes'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like is killing you, especially with that leading wildcard which completely removes any indexes the columns may have.

You should look into using SQL Server's full-text indexing.  `contains` will probably be much faster and is far more powerful for partial matches of the nature you appear to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

well, you could implement a full-text index on that column which would help performance of select statements, but hurt performance of the other three CRUD operations as the index would need to be updated on each operation. Then I believe you'd use a CONTAINS or some other similar keyword. Here's some more [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142559.aspx).